# Firebase verify user before sign up

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to verify a user before I can allow signup, however, the verification always fails on the first call even when data is correct

```
private var isAprroved : Boolean = false

fun signUp(email: String, password: String, idNumber: String): Task<AuthResult>? {
        verifyApprovedUser(idNumber)
        return if (isAprroved) {
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    private fun verifyApprovedUser(idNumber: String) {
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.child(idNumber).exists()) {
                   updateUserVerified()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })

    }

    fun updateUserVerified() {
        isAprroved = true
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `signUp`? it should be called after `updateUserVerified()` .

Comment: @ADM I’m calling sign up from a view model and it’s returns the auth result

Comment: You are probably calling it before `isAprroved` is getting set . These two method call should be sequential because `signUp` depends upon the output of `verifyApprovedUser` .

Comment: @ADM how can I ensure that the firebaseAuth waits for the results of verifyApprovedUser??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isAprroved` is always `false` since `verifyApprovedUser` function calls an asynchronous function, so `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` will be called before `onDataChange` function.

To fix this, you have to change `verifyApprovedUser` to return `Task<Boolean>` with using [TaskCompletionSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource) and chaining by using `continueWithTask` in `signUp` function, something like this. (I didn't test code though)

**Kotlin Version:**

```
private fun signUp(email: String, password: String, idNumber: String): Task<AuthResult?> {
    return verifyApprovedUser(idNumber).continueWithTask { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            return@continueWithTask Tasks.forException<AuthResult?>(task.exception!!)
        }
        val verified: Boolean = task.result
        if (verified) {
            return@continueWithTask FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        } else {
            return@continueWithTask Tasks.forResult<AuthResult?>(null)
        }
    }
}

private fun verifyApprovedUser(idNumber: String): Task<Boolean> {
    val tcs: TaskCompletionSource<Boolean> = TaskCompletionSource()
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val verified = dataSnapshot.child(idNumber).exists()
            tcs.setResult(verified)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            tcs.setException(databaseError.toException())
        }
    })
    return tcs.task
}
```

**Java Version:**

```
private Task<AuthResult> signUp(String email, String password, String idNumber) {
    return verifyApprovedUser(idNumber).continueWithTask(task -> {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            return Tasks.forException(task.getException());
        }
        boolean verified = task.getResult();
        if (verified) {
            return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        } else {
            return Tasks.forResult(null);
        }
    });
}

private Task<Boolean> verifyApprovedUser(String idNumber) {
    TaskCompletionSource<Boolean> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean verified = dataSnapshot.child(idNumber).exists();
            tcs.setResult(verified);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            tcs.setException(databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
    return tcs.getTask();
}
```

However, a recommended approach would be `RxJava` and Kotlin's `Coroutine`.

Plus, you would better to learn what `Reactive Programming` is.

Comment: This answer is in a different language from what OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how efficient this is , but this is how i managed to implement

```
 val approvedUsersList : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

fun signUp(email: String, password: String, idNumber: String): Task<AuthResult>? {
        verifyApprovedUsers()
        if (idNumber in approvedUsersList){
           return firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    private fun verifyApprovedUsers() {
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                approvedUsersList.clear()
                for (data: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    approvedUsersList.add(data.value.toString())
                }

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: I updated the answer, simply transform the java code to kotlin :)

Comment: I updated the Kotlin version too, ask me if you have any question.

Comment: I tried the method though it doesn't return null, and if I try to query the result of the return value I get Task is not complete error

Comment: Did you figure out the workaround? If you didn't I will test the code and fix the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my Login Activity Verifies if I already logged in before.

```
private fun verifyIfUserIsLoggedIn() { // Checks if user has already logged in
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid

        // This checks if there is a present UID in your Activity
        // If UID == null, intent closes the CurrentActivity and throws you back in RegisterActivity
        if (uid == null) {
            val intent = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) // Clears previous activity when inflating the new one
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: p.s. Still working fine for me. If youre still confused as to how Im able to do this. Just comment here ;)

Comment: I don’t understand how the user is being verified

Comment: @Crucialjun Sorry bro, I sent the wrong code. I edited it, and entered the right one. Try this and it should work. Dont forget to put the function `onCreate`.